# Best php practise display errors

Tags: php

Is there best practice about display errors in during controller action executing on view? I mean, how do you display errors when 'login was not found in database' or 'input value has incorrect format', or 'field require value'?

Is there array with errors or anything else? Now my code looks like:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $siteName = isset($_POST['SiteName']) ? trim($_POST['SiteName']) : null;
    $siteUrl = isset($_POST['SiteUrl']) ? trim($_POST['SiteUrl']) : null;

    if(IsNullOrEmptyString($siteName) || IsNullOrEmptyString($siteUrl)) {
        exit('Site name or site url could not be empty');
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^http\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?$/', $siteUrl)){
        exit('Site url has wrong format');
    }

    $filters = array('SiteName' => $siteName, 'SiteUrl' => $siteUrl);
    if($sitesRepository->select($filters)) {
        exit('Site is already exist');
    }
}
```

But if i use exit, my page doesn't continue to display.

Comment: You didnt tell me anything what i've already known ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to store all the errors and keep processing, you can put them into an array. Before you process define an array and then add each error to that array. For example:

```
$arrErrors = array();
```

Then replace your exit statements with:

```
$arrErrors[] = 'The error text goes here...';
```

When you're done processing, you can check for and output any errors:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($arrErrors); $i++)
{
    echo $arrErrors[$i].'<br />'; 
}
```

or

```
echo implode('<br />', $arrErrors);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, `exit()` (and `die()`) terminate output. It is also a lazy way of ensuring code doesn't get executed once a problem arises, but there are better, more scalable approaches.

One is to commit any error into a variable then check for it before executing any code that is conditional on an error not having yet appeared. Then, when we get to output, we relay the error to the user.

```
//let's say some error just occurred
$error = 'some error!';

//some code that should happen only if there's no error yet
if (!isset($error)) doSomething();

//then, when we get to output, display any error
if (isset($error)) echo "<h3 class='error'>".$error."</h3>";
```

EDIT - as sk00V rightly says, you may also want to log multiple errors, for which push them into an array. My example assumed you would want to quit at the first error, which is what your code suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Its never a best practice to actually show what has gone wrong with the system.

```
//let's say some error just occurred
$error = 'some error!';

//some code that should happen only if there's no error yet
if (!isset($error)) doSomething();

//then, when we get to output, display any error
if (isset($error)) header("Location: error.html");
```

If anything goes wrong with the code, rather than showing the error, just redirect the user to an Custom error page, and show some message that will not cause the user to worry much about the problem. Rather than showing him that his records werent found in the Database, which might cause him to get scared.

Just redirect him to the error page, and show him that, you know what has gone wrong and your team is working on it right now to get it fixed.

(showing some humorous error messages might help you out)

Comment: Yeah, its very helpfull on registration page, where i have to show user, that his login is already exist in database

Comment: Well if it already exists just tell him that the email is already registered and you can just tell him to login with his password!